# Active Directory (2012) - Allow "SELF" to read attribute with confidential bit set.

Tags: active-directory

I have extended my schema to include a field called mobilePrivate. I have set the searchFlags for this attribute to 128 bits to make it confidential.

Now I am trying to allow user accounts to read/write to this attribute. I have the write part down but when they try to read it back they can't. I have run the LDP.EXE tools provided with Windows Sever 2012 and given the NT AUTHORITY\SELF permissions on the OU where all the users are located yet it still can not read it's own field.

Anybody have any idea's to get this working? I need to give the users the ability to enter in their own private phone numbers without the data showing up in LDAP browses.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://www.frickelsoft.net/blog/?p=151), they also need the 'Control Access' permission.

> CF: Mark this attribute as confidential. This bit marks attributes as
>   confidential so it can only be read by securityPrincipals that have
>   special permission (“Read” and “Control Access”) to it.

Also, make sure you don't have any 'Deny' permissions that would apply to the user. 'Deny' takes precedence over 'Allow'.

Comment: You sir are a genious! That fixed it I have been working on this dumb thing for hours. A+