# How to give users the permission to read their own confidential attributes?

Tags: active-directory

I have added a new attribute to the Active Directory schema. In this field I want to store a provisioning link for a software. This link is unique for each user and should not be readable by everyone. Therefore I set the searchFlag of the attribute to 128 (confidential). However, the user should have the possibility to read out the attribute with his personal value.

Now I tried to give "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" read permissions for the attribute as described on [Active Directory (2012) - Allow "SELF" to read attribute with confidential bit set.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892532/active-directory-2012-allow-self-to-read-attribute-with-confidential-bit-s).

Unfortunately this does not work. Even if I give "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" full access, the attribute is not displayed. I also tried with a group instead of "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" with the same result.

If I use the Administrator account, everything works fine.

To test, I retrieve the data with the following command in PowerShell.

```
(([adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=User)(sAMAccountName=$env:USERNAME))").findall()).properties
```